# onPress and onChangeText doing nothing in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My `onPress` & `onChangeText` functions doing nothing. If I entered the value, I got this error message

```
_this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState({
          username: username
        })', '_this.setState' is undefined)
```

app/index.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: "", 
      password: ""
    };

    this._handlePress = this._handlePress.bind(this)
  }

  _handlePress = () => {
     const { username } = this.state;
     const { password } = this.state;

     Alert.alert(username);
     Alert.alert(password);
     onSignIn().then(() => navigation.navigate("SignedIn")); //also not working
  }

  /**/

  render() {
    /**/
  }
}
```

app/screens/SignIn.js

```
import React from "react";

export default ({navigation, _handlePress}) => (
  <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
    <Card title="SIGN IN">
      <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
      <FormInput 
        placeholder="Email address..." 
        onChangeText={username => this.setState({username})}
      />
      <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
      <FormInput 
        secureTextEntry 
        placeholder="Password..." 
        onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
      />

      <Button
        buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
        backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
        title="SIGN IN"
        onPress={this._handlePress}
      />
    </Card>
  </View>
);
```

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/auth-reactnative

Comment: You cannot run `this.setState` in a functional component. This component
`app/screens/SignIn.js`

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error as SignIn.js js is just a function and not a Component class. so the function's 'this' does not have any method 'setstate'. You need to write the component within a react class like this

```
class Signin extends React.Component{

  <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
      <Card title="SIGN IN">
        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
        <FormInput 
          placeholder="Email address..." 
          onChangeText={username => this.setState({username})}
        />
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput 
          secureTextEntry 
          placeholder="Password..." 
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}
        />

        <Button
          buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
          backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
          title="SIGN IN"
          onPress={this._handlePress}
        />
      </Card>
    </View>
}
```

Comment: thats correct, my SignIn.js is just a function and not a Component class. I need to stay in this way since Im using navigation.

Comment: then you should pass in the handlers to your Signin function

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// i have cloned your repo and run it successfully, by moving username 
// and password from index.js to SignIn.js, rewrite SignIn in class way, 
// navigation works well(jump to signed successfuly after pressing). 
// however not sure if this is what you need.
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { View, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Card, Button, FormLabel, FormInput } from "react-native-elements";

export default class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  _handlePress () {

    let {navigation} = this.props;

    navigation.navigate("SignedIn")
  }

  _handleUChange (username) {
    this.setState({username})
  }

  _handlePChange (password) {
    this.setState({password})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
        <Card title="SIGN IN">
          <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
          <FormInput 
            placeholder="Email address..." 
            onChangeText={this._handleUChange.bind(this)}
          />
          <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
          <FormInput 
            secureTextEntry 
            placeholder="Password..." 
            onChangeText={this._handlePChange.bind(this)}
          />

          <Button
            buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
            backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
            title="SIGN IN"
            onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}
          />
        </Card>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I got a new error message. Almost the same with the previous one.

_changeState is not a function. (In '_changeState({
          username: username
        })', '_changeState' is undefined)

Comment: you need to pass the method '_changeState' through props where you use <Signin _changeState={_changeState}/>

Comment: how to do that? any sample? I already bind it in the constructor.     this._changeState = this._changeState.bind(this)

Comment: sorry for missing the module 'react-navigation',  here i suggest to keep 'username and password' in page Signin.js, verify login status and then use global navigation object to jump, pass the navigation object in page router.js through props, and then we can access to it in page Signin.js

Comment: If you look it closely, my this.state is not in the component. index.js and SignIn.js are different things.